# MongoDB Updating Collections

Tags: mongodb, collections, key

I haven't been able to set up my MongoDB yet, so unfortunately I cannot test this myself. I plan on having a collection that will be updated frequently. There may be data in the collection that is not changed when an update occurs. Will that data remain available after the update? For instance:

```
db.statistics_db.games.1234.statistics = {a:1,b:2,c:3}
db.statistics_db.games.1234.update('statistics',{a:2,d:1,e:4})
```

This way the final result will be `{a:2,b:2,c:3,d:1,e:4}`, is that what I can expect to happen? Or will the data simply be replaced entirely? How can I achieve what I expected if this is not the case? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, found an answer here: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating+Data+in+Mongo

The solution seems to be to call the data you want to update, make changes by iterating through the new data and replacing the old, then update the database with all data. If anyone finds a better way of doing this please let me know.

Comment: I don't see anything on that page suggesting what you describe. Generally you would set the new values and the old ones would remain as they are. If it's a whole subdocument you either set subfields you want to set/change or replace the whole document.